# How can I style tkz-euclide points?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tkz-euclide

The `tkz-euclide` package lets you do things like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} \tkzDefPoint(4,0){B} \tkzDefPoint(2,3){C}
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
  \tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,A)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, by default, the point style is filled with a semi-transparent black.* Using `\tkzDrawPoints[fill=black]` fixes this, but it would be nice to be able to style all the points to, by default, use a black fill.

What styles, TikZ or tkz-euclide, should I use to accomplish this?

---

* *Note for posterity:*
It's *not* actually a semi-transparent black.
Rather, it's a solid gray.
Moving the `\tkzDrawPoints` command after the `\tkzDrawSegments` command makes this clear.

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} \tkzDefPoint(4,0){B} \tkzDefPoint(2,3){C}
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)  % want them filled
  \tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
\tkzSetUpPoint[<options>]
```

to customize the attributes for points. An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\tkzSetUpPoint[fill=black]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} \tkzDefPoint(4,0){B} \tkzDefPoint(2,3){C}
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)  % want them filled
  \tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]